# Liferay linking - Langue web content - how to get the url linked the languages

Tags: liferay

enter code hereIn liferay there is a web content created that handle the Language issue , i didnt used it , i putted an img and want to link it to a language , with 2 images , for 2 langhuae Arabic and english, but what i dont know is the link to this content, as:

```
<a-href="????"><img srr="..."></a>
```

where can i get the url that attach me to the needed language...
regards

Answer (score 0):

Well here is the solution we could found.

First of all, the common pattern for this behavior is that the download window was shown when a link was clicked (an anchor).

We changed our href addresses from something like "/web/guest/page-name" to something like "/en/web/guest/page-name" for english, and "/esp/web/guest/page-name" for Arabic.

Comment: that what i did and surely it worked but i think that its not a Perfect solution u know..still trying to find a better solution

Comment: any solution found for this case?